# How do I add form errors for a model that belongs to another model, rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm following along with the [Rails Guides - Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial. It makes a basic Post model, and a Comment model that belongs to Post.

I have added a simple validation to the Comment model, and it works, but I can't figure out how to get form errors to display if I fill it out wrong.

Here is my comment.rb model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :body, presence: true
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Here is the original form for adding a comment, it's in posts/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the original create action in comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

I've tried quite a few things, but it all feels like fumbling around in the dark. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [dynamic_form gem](https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form) - this used to be part of Rail itself but was extracted a while back. With it, you can display errors inline like this:

```
<%= f.label :commenter %><br />
<%= f.text_field :commenter %>
<%= f.error_message_on :commenter %>
```

Comment: worked! Quick note to anyone who reads this: Don't forget to restart the server after gem install!